# Load and preview images in many inputs

Tags: javascript, image, input, filereader

I have form with 4 inputs to load a images and preview them. The script below work but only for first input

```
<input type="file" id="images-upload-input-1" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" name="image_1" onchange="previewFile(event);" value="img/<?echo $row['zdjecie'];?>" style='display: none;'/>

    function previewFile() {
    const preview = document.getElementById('img-new-1'); 
    const file = document.getElementById('images-upload-1').files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function () 
          {
            // convert image file to base64 string
            preview.src = reader.result;
          }, false);

    if (file) 
        {
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
};
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code around:

I added a `data-img` to each file input so that it would be tied to an img by it's id. Then I updated the preview function to use the event passed `e` to use the input that was changed and not referring directly to a single ID.

```js
function previewFile(e) {
    const preview = document.querySelector(e.target.dataset.img); 
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function () 
          {
            // convert image file to base64 string
            preview.src = reader.result;
          }, false);

    if (file) 
        {
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
};
```

```html
<input data-img="#img-new-1" type="file" id="images-upload-input-1" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" name="image_1" onchange="previewFile(event);" value="img/"/>

<input data-img="#img-new-2" type="file" id="images-upload-input-2" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" name="image_2" onchange="previewFile(event);" value="img/"/>

<img id="img-new-1">
<img id="img-new-2">
```